# Does it matter who destroys the car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Buying the scrapyard means you get money for every car you destroy. Does that only count the destruction of cars by that one character? Or can you blow up cars with any of the three and still obtain the money?

Answer (score 10):

Cars destroyed (no matter by whom) will end up in the scrap yard, for the profit of the character with that property.

Comment: Great answer, just in case anyone is looking for a guide for the properties: http://geekfed.com/grand-theft-auto-5-property-tips/390